# Border gap and border again

Tags: html, css, border

I got stuck when I'm trying to do something with borders, Here's a photo of my work:

[image]

You see that there's a border on that "play.oyunbaz.network" stuff. I want to make the bottom of photo bordered to to create a good view but I don't want to border the bottom of that "play.oyunbaz.network" thing.

I tried to use `z-index` but it did not work.

```css
.ipbar .row .col-md-6 {
  color: #4c4c4c;
  background-color: #eeeeee;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #4c4c4c;
  border-width: 5px 5px 0px 5px;
  border-top-left-radius: 15px;
  border-top-right-radius: 15px;
}
.ipbar .row .col-md-6 p {
  font-size: 40px;
  margin-bottom: -5px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #9bb0c8 !important;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="container ipbar">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 text-center">
      <div class="oyunbaz-ip">
        <p>play.oyunbaz.network</p>
        <span>connect now and join <strong>700</strong> other players now!</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/ZDg3pY8.png Can you see the red lines in the photo? I want to make something like that in the same color with the border of play.oyunbaz.network element.

Comment: by the way sorry for my bad english, I am trying my best to explain my problem.

Comment: So why not give both the borders the same color?

Comment: When I do that the bottom of the play.oyunbaz.network thing's bottom looks like its bordered too. Didnt u check out the second link that i've given.

Comment: Where do you want to add the border? Below the "play.oyunbaz.network" element or the whole header or below everything except the "play.oyunbaz.network" element?

Comment: except the play.oyunbaz.network thing.

Comment: I don't see a border below that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.top {
  border-bottom: 5px solid #4c4c4c;
}
.ipbar{  }
.ipbar .row .col-md-6 {
  color: #4c4c4c;
  background-color: #eeeeee;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #4c4c4c;
  border-width: 5px 5px 0px 5px;
  border-top-left-radius: 15px;
  border-top-right-radius: 15px;
  z-index:1000; 
  bottom:-5px;
}

.ipbar .row .col-md-6 p {
  font-size: 40px;
  margin-bottom: -5px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #9bb0c8 !important;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="top">
<div class="container ipbar">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 text-center">
      <div class="oyunbaz-ip">
        <p>
          play.oyunbaz.network
        </p>
        <span>
          connect now and join <strong>700</strong> other players now!
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Is this what you want? Try viewing it on Full Page mode(Expand Snippet).

Comment: Actually I thought this way but it didnot work but thanks anyway.